# Remove duplicate JSON blocks from file using JQ

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I have a JSON file that contains thousands of entries, and i need to remove the duplicate blocks.

**Here is an example of the file:**

```
{ "signatures": [
   {
     "signatureId": 0050,
     "mode": 0
   },
   {
     "signatureId": 0012,
     "mode": 0
   },
   {
     "signatureId": 0012,
     "mode": 1
   }
]}
```

**Here is the target result to achieve:**

```
{ "signatures": [
   {
     "signatureId": 0050,
     "mode": 0
   },
   {
     "signatureId": 0012,
     "mode": 0
   }
]}
```

And as you see, the "mode" value doesnt matter, what really matters is that the "signatureId" must not be duplicate, so when we remove the whole block, which ever "mode" stays, its not a problem.

I can only use Shell and/or JQ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `unique_by` with the field to be checked for duplicates as its argument. It will always take the first of a kind (here, the one with `"mode": 0`)

```bash
jq '.signatures |= unique_by(.signatureId)'
```

```json
{
  "signatures": [
    {
      "signatureId": 12,
      "mode": 0
    },
    {
      "signatureId": 50,
      "mode": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/9IRrIRjLNqn)

Comment: perfect! works like magic, thanks so much